# ISession per Request (Only when necessary)

Tags: nhibernate, orm, request, sessionfactory, isession

I'm developing an application (asp.net mvc) and I'm using ISession per request (in globa.asax I use Bind and Unbind in Begin_Request event and End_Request event). Everything works fine but sometimes (some requests) I don't need to use an ISession (a connection with database).

I'd like to know if is there any way to open an ISession only when I need and make the ISession entry in all process request (to be shared with all repositories and a unique context of transaction) ?

I'm developnig and penny auction website and my server will have many request per second and sometimes I don't need the connection, I'll use a Cache.

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted that opening a session does not imply opening a connection to the database. As noted in [this article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/16/what-is-the-cost-of-opening-a-session.aspx), the cost of opening a session is extremely low. So, in general, I wouldn't worry about requests opening a session when they don't need it; essentially you're just newing up a very lightweight object.

Comment: I didn't know about that, maybe it doesn't have a problem. Thanks!

Comment: I can highly recommend NHProf if you need to have a birds-eye view of what's happening under the covers with NHibernate. If nothing else, this should help to verify that no database interaction is taking place in the emtpy sessions.

Comment: Hi @DanP, Yes, I'm using NHProf to see with more details, and really some pages I get a empty session. I'll implement the chronometer for penny auction and each second my app will have a request. Just like you recommand and Ayenge article, it will not be a problem =D. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ActionFilter to do this.  Here's one that I use to do exactly what you describe.

```
public class UsingNhibernate : ActionFilterAttribute {
    private ISession nhSession;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        nhSession = NHHelper.OpenSession();
        nhSession.BeginTransaction();
        // set an accessible reference to your nhSession for access from elsewhere
        //   ((ApplicationController)filterContext.Controller).nHSession = nhSession; is what I do
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        try {
            if (filterContext.Exception == null && nhSession != null && nhSession.Transaction.IsActive)
                nhSession.Transaction.Commit();
            else if (nhSession != null && nhSession.Transaction.IsActive)
                nhSession.Transaction.Rollback();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (nhSession != null && nhSession.Transaction.IsActive)
                nhSession.Transaction.Rollback();
            nhSession.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
        nhSession.Dispose();
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

On each appropriate controller action (or even at the controller level to apply to all actions) you simply add the UsingNhibernate action filter like so:

```
[UsingNhibernate]
public ActionResult SaveSystemSetting(SystemAdminVM item) {
```